# Excel SQL data type mismatch

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RawData$] 
WHERE 'Temperature[°C]' <= 100
```

But at the execution I get this error:

*Data type mismatch in criteria expression.*

The data in this column is 100% integer so I guess there is no problem.

Further this works fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RawData$] 
WHERE 'Temperature[°C]'
```

I also tried this too but then I get no values at all:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RawData$] 
WHERE 'Temperature[°C]' <= '100'
```

Actually the final question would be:

What query do i need to search a column which name is: Temperature[°C]

`[Temperature[°C]]`
`[Temperature[[]°C]]`

do not work.

Comment: You are trying to compare a string ('Temperature[°C]') with an integer (100). You probably want to access a *row* named "Temperature[°C]"

Comment: Yes, any idea, how i do that?

Comment: Not without seeing your dataset. `'` signs are only for strings in SQL, so if you column is called `Temperature` you should probably have it in square brackets, or maybe double quotes.

Comment: Also, find the person who put `[°C]` in the column name of a table and beat him/her about the head. That's just being cruel and obtuse! `TemperatureC` would have been more than sufficient to convey meaning without causing people to have to jump through all kinds of ridiculous hoops to write their queries. (Most people probably don't know that `Alt-248` on the num pad will give them the degree symbol.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `WHERE 'Temperature[°C]' <= 100` compares the literal string `Temperature[°C]` to the Integer `100`.

Use `WHERE [Temperature(°C)] < 100` instead.

**Note:**

- square brackets `[]` are reserved to be wrapped around fieldnames (much like you tried to use single quotes `'`)
- in this particular case, the square brackets in your header get interpreted as normal brackets `()`.

Comment: no worries. make your life easier by always using database-conform headers in excel-tables that you *might* query with sql

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what's happening here... can you explain how this worked if his column name is `Temperature[°C]`? I tried `WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'TEST' "Temperature[°C]") SELECT [Temperature(°C)] FROM CTE` with error `Invalid column name 'Temperature(°C)'.`. I'm trying to wrap my head around this! I don't ever deal with brackets in column names.

Comment: @justiceorjustus In short: To get the values from your Excel-column `Temperature[°C]` (square brackets as part of the name) we have to know that SQL internally replaces that name with `Temperature(°C)` (Our SQL will look like this: `SELECT * FROM [RawData$] WHERE [Temperature(°C)] < 100`). This is because in SQL code, square brackets are **reserved as wrappers around columnnames/tablenames**, similar to the way that single/double quotes are reserved as wrappers around strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the column name has square brackets, so you have to maybe do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RawData$] 
WHERE "Temperature[°C]" <= '100'
```

With the double quotes, instead. Let me know if that works.

Comment: for field- and tablenames, sql uses square brackets `[]` instead of quotes `'`/`"`. both single and double quotes are always interpreted as the wrappers of a string.

Comment: @MartinDreher I'm going to disagree.  You can try `SELECT "TEST"` and it interprets "TEST" as a column name with error `Invalid column name 'TEST'.` Doing `SELECT 'TEST' "TEST"` uses an alias in the double quotes.  Doing `SELECT 'TEST' "[TEST]"` allows for brackets in the column name.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong. You can do `SELECT "Column" FROM Table`, `SELECT Column FROM Table`, and `SELECT [Column] FROM Table` all with the same result.